# How can I make my bot say full sentences that I say?

Tags: discord, discord.py

This is the code I am using currently:

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, arg: str):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(f"{arg}")
```

This code works, but the bot only says the first word of the sentence. How can I make it say the whole sentence?

Comment: try `await ctx.send(' '.join(arg))`

Comment: and by the way, the proper way to delete the current message is `await ctx.message.delete()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this would work:

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.message.delete()

    # do you want to say it with TTS ?
    await ctx.send(' '.join(args), tts=True)
```